# codeigniter: I have rows in database (think like a blog post, title, postbody etc). What methods are there to present a form + save the submission?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, edit

Basically I am using codeigniter  and have LOTS of fields in each row for a database table.

(for this example I'll pretend its a blog entry with just title/postbody but thats only to keep it simple)

I know i could manually code in something like this:

(psedudo code)

```
if (!$submitted) {
   $data = get_existing_data_from_db();
$showform=true;
}
if ($submitted) {

   if (process_and_save_data_if_all_valid_data()) {

       echo "done";

   }
else {

$data = get_data_from_submitted_data();
$showform=true;

}

}


if ($showform) {

echo "<form>";
echo "<input type='text' name='title' value='{$data->title}' />";

}
```

but is there any CI class or library that would let me do something more along the lines of this (again, pseudo code)

```
$fields_to_edit = array('title','postbody');
$this->form_helper->edit_table_with_fields('posts', $fields_to_edit);
```

and the form_helper thing would automatically validate (obviously id set the rules) + show the form to the user, and save it (update mysql) if all correct

does something like this exist for code igintor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form builder may make things easier for you. http://formigniter.org/

I think what you're looking for is a "codeigniter CRUD generator", just Google this and you will find quite a few. Picking one is up to you. [Example 1](http://www.grocerycrud.com/), [Example 2](http://code.google.com/p/ci-scaffold/)...